# R: sorting by rownames

Tags: r, sorting

I'm looking to sort my data in a fairly unusual way and can't seem to manage it.
I have rownames as follows:
`CLSTRU

TBSVOD

TRUCLS

VODTBS`

As you can see, the first three characters have been switched with the last 3 characters. I would like to sort it in the following way:
`CLSTRU

TRUCLS

TBSVOD

VODTBS`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Only some of the items appear to have been "switched". How are you decide which ones?

Comment: @DWin, thanks for the response. The switch is simply to ensure that any two rows where the first 3 characters match the last 3 of the other and vice versa are next to each other i.e. such that CLSTRU is above TRUCLS. Apart from that the actual ordering is irrelevant. Thanks again!

Comment: I think that my guesswork solution accomplishes that goal, although you may need to use a secondary argument to `order if you want all of the AAAZZZ's next to each other if there are also AAADDD's in the mix..

Comment: @DWin. I just tried it now, but it seems to put it by alphabetical order, rather than placing two entries where the first 3 characters of one match the second 3 characters of the other & vice versa next to each other. Thanks

Comment: I should have used `pmin()`. Try it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps (guessing you want the "minimum" value of the two triplets as the sorting criterion):

```
 dfrm[ order( pmin(substr( rownames(dfrm), 1,3),substr( rownames(dfrm), 4,6) ) ),
        , ]
```

Test:

```
dat <- c('CLSTRU',
 'TBSVOD',
 'TRUCLS',
 'VODTBS')

 dat[ order( pmin(substr( dat, 1,3),substr( dat, 4,6) ) )]
#[1] "CLSTRU" "TRUCLS" "TBSVOD" "VODTBS"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I don't think that will work, as it orders it by the first character. Sorry, perhaps my data were not a good choice, as the actual data aren't in alphabetical order. I will change that quick to make it more representative.

Comment: by the way, when I applied this to a different dataset I had to change pmin to pmax, but that made it work. Thanks again!

Answer (score -3):

I know nothing of r, but I wonder if you could:

1. Copy your rows to one of 2 arrays - "array1", and "array2". In order for a row to be copied to array 1, compare the first 3 characters to the last 3 characters of all entries already in "array1". If they ARE found like that (ie, this "current" row is a "back to front row"), copy that element to array 2 instead - this way, array1 contains the "normal way round" rows, and array2 contains the "back to front" rows.
2. Once you have processed all rows (and if all has worked, array1.length = array2.length = number of rows/2) - create a final array of data, adding: array1.row1 array2.row1, array1.row2, array2.row2 etc etc

??

Answer (score -4):

I think simple unix sort command can do this, please check the following commands:

$ sort demo

ABCDEF

DEFABC

HIJKLM

KLMHIJ

Thanks